# NginX cannot redirect to React App

Tags: nginx, proxy, reverse-proxy, redirect, proxypass

I'm quite new to NginX, so my apologies if anything I ask here sounds naive.
Lets say I have a DNS **www.example.com**.

Whenever a request comes to `www.example.com/` (only `/`), I want NginX to redirect it to `www.example.com/home`, which in turn will forward the request to a React app running on port 5000.
Whenever a request comes to `www.example.come/{anything}`, I want my Springboot application, running on 3001, to handle that.

So I have the following configuration

**example.conf**

```
server {

        server_name example.com www.example.com;

        listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot

        location = / {
                return 301 https://$host/home;
        }

        location / {

                proxy_pass http://localhost:3001;
                proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        }

        location = /home {
                proxy_pass http://localhost:5000;
        }
}
```

And I have the following **react-app.conf**

```
server {

        listen 5000;
        server_name localhost;

        root /home/ubuntu/example/frontend/build;
        index index.html;

        location / {
        }
}
```

This path `/home/ubuntu/example/frontend/build` is where my react app's build folder is sitting.

Now whenever I try to access `www.example.com/xxx` or `www.example.com/xyz`, my Springboot app is getting called, but whenever I try only `www.example.com`, it first redirects to `www.example.com/home` and then shows the generic **404** NginX error page.

I checked the error logs. It prints the follwing:

```
2020/02/11 19:21:31 [error] 12936#12936: *15 open() "/home/ubuntu/example/frontend/build/home" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 127.0.0.1, server: localhost, request: "GET /home HTTP/1.0", host: "localhost:5000"
```

What I don't understand here is why it's trying to open `/home/ubuntu/example/frontend/build/home`. Where is that trailing **/home** coming from and how to take care of it?

I checked [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/925051/how-to-run-multiple-react-apps-on-same-domain-using-nginx#_=_) and [this](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/request_processing.html), but they didn't help much

**Edit 1**

I made the changes suggested in the comment section and my **example.conf** now looks like the following:

```
server {

            server_name example.com www.example.com;

            listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot

            location = / {
                    return 301 https://$host/home;
            }

            location / {

                    proxy_pass http://localhost:3001;
                    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            }

            location = /home {
                    proxy_pass http://localhost:5000/;
            }
    }
```

However, now I don't get any error in NginX error logs, but I do see my Springboot app getting invoked. What's happening is, `example.com` is going to `example.com/home`, which is then going to `http://localhost:3001` where my Springboot app is currently running.

But this isn't supposed to happen since on `/home`, it should have been taken to the NginX server running on port 5000. Is there any changes I need to make in my **react-app.conf** file?

Comment: If you want to remove the `/home` from the URI before you pass it to the service at 5000, try: `proxy_pass http://localhost:5000/;`

Comment: @RichardSmith I just tried what you suggested. While I didn't get any error logs, I got logs on my Springboot app running on port 3001, which is not supposed to happen because the request is supposed to be proxy passed to the nginx server listening on port 5000. Any idea why that might be happening?

Comment: Go back to the way you had it before the edit because that error was giving you a 404 on the second server block. The second server block is looking for the URL that the 301 redirected the browser to. That url is example.com/home. Since you didn't redirect to example.com/index.html, nginx is trying to resolve the "path". See my answer for the solution.

Answer (score 0):

You're URL is looking for /home -> That's a file. But you want to send all requests to `index.html`.

Use `try_files`:

`location / {
    try_files index.html =404;
}`

http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#try_files

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7027636/nginx-send-all-requests-to-a-single-html-page

```
server {

        listen 5000;
        server_name localhost;

        root /home/ubuntu/example/frontend/build;
        index index.html;

        location / {
           try_files index.html =404;
        }
}
```

Comment: I did what you suggested, that is change `proxy_pass http://localhost:5000/;` to `proxy_pass http://localhost:5000;` and change what you suggested here. I am still getting a **404 Not Found**

Comment: is there a file called index.html? What is the error message now?